# using beautiful soup on local content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I started a research project grabbing pages using wget with the local links and mirror options. I did it this way at the time to get the data as I did not know how long the sites would be active. So I have 60-70 sites fully mirrored with localized links sitting in a dir. I now need to gleam what I can from them.

Is there a good example of parsing these pages using beautifulsoup? I realize that beautifulsoup is designed to take the http request and parse from there. I will be honest, I'm not savvy on beautifulsoup yet and my programming skills are not awesome. Now that I have some time to devote to it, I would like to do this the easy way versus the manual way.

Can someone point me to a good example, resource, or tutorial for parsing the html I have stored? I really appreciate it. Am I over-thinking this?

Comment: Also check out Scrapy.

Answer (score 3):

Using BeautifulSoup with local contents are just the same with Internet contents. For example, to read a local html file into bs4:

```
    response = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///Users/Li/Desktop/test.html', timeout=1)
    html = response.read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

In terms of how to use bs4 for processing html, the documentation of bs4 is a pretty good tutorial. In most situation, spending a day reading it is enough for basic data processing.

```
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse a document, pass it into the BeautifulSoup constructor. You can pass in a string or an **open filehandle**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>data</html>")
```